# Chrome debugging jquery consistent error.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

My skills with web development aren't yet quite developed.
I'm getting this consistent error anytime I launch a localhost webpage:

```
"GET http://clkmon.com/adServe/banners?tid=10029_12620_12&tagid=2 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT"
```

This is the output in Chrome debugging console.
This started when I was working with page that was already developed and I didn't pay much attention, but now I notice I get this error for every page I was working - even if it was an empty html file. I have no idea how is this happening because there is no link to a jquery script, and I am suspicious about this clkmon.com/adServe...

Any help is appreciated.

More Info:

```
GET http://clkmon.com/adServe/banners?tid=10029_12620_12&tagid=2 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
    (anonymous function)                               @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:25
    propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function)  @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
    EventImpl.dispatchToListener                       @ extensions::event_bindings:395
    propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function)  @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
    $Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function)    @ extensions::utils:94
    EventImpl.dispatch_                                @ extensions::event_bindings:379
    EventImpl.dispatch                                 @ extensions::event_bindings:401
    propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function)  @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
    $Array.forEach.publicClass.(anonymous function)    @ extensions::utils:94
    dispatchOnMessage                                  @ extensions::messaging:316
```

Comment: You have some adware addon, i suppose  - check page at incognito mode ( Run Chrome in incognito mode ant check page )

Comment: Or it can be Adblock message, are you using some kind of ads blocking extension?

Comment: Without Adblock I get this response:  - pw1.0 @ VM556:1 pw1.0 - Im not liking this VM556

Comment: How can I tag this post as Solved? (sorry, im really a newbie posting here...)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a chrome extension which sends this request to show you the ads.

Go to chrome://extensions and remove/disable all extensions you don't know or don't like

Comment: If that doesn't work, if you're using wordpress or some other framework for your pages, you should also check that it isn't being injected on the server side.

Comment: Oh, I know what it can be. Thanks a lot: ill confirm the if the extension Im thinking about was the responsable for this.

Comment: No wordpress - I develop from scratch.

Comment: Yes - It was an extension - Thanks a lot. It was GrooveShark or Wareztuga extension. Both disable and problem fixed.

Comment: you are welcome :) @Radio it cannot be a wordpress because of error message which explicitly says that it comes from extensions

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have clkmon.com malware on your PC.  Google "clkmon.com malware" for a fix.

Comment: Found the problem: it wasn't malware, it was an extension.

Comment: Yep - more than a third of Chrome extensions are classified by Google as malware.  Glad this was an easy fix for you.